# Installation Ubuntu 14.04 on Desktop

Tags: dual-boot

Will a dual-boot install automatically prepare an ubuntu-partition and on which logical unit?

How can one uninstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you specify your question please. How does you system currently look like (which system is installed, how many partitions) ? Why do you want uninstall Ubuntu ?

Comment: Hi, Currently Pentium 4, 1GB RAM, XP3, 2 Partitions C & D            I do not intend to uninstall Ubuntu presently; but just in case, so that I know HOW at all and am prepared. If not possible, then I would have major concern!

Answer (score 1):

Normally Ubuntu will automatically prepare a partition here is the [official install guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).

Don't forget to make a **backup before installing!**

I recommend you another modification of Ubuntu, use [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) it will run faster on your Hardware.

Use the **32Bit** version for your PC.

If you want to dual-boot chose the option **Install Ubuntu** (or Xubuntu/Lubuntu) **alongside Windows** on the install menu.

Uninstalling is no  problem here is an [guide](http://bobmorris.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/how-to-uninstall-ubuntu-on-dual-boot-windows-xp-using-windows-only/).

But keep in mind Windows XP should no longer be used for the Internet because the update support is out of date!

---

**Edit: How to turn Ubuntu into Lubuntu without reinstall:**

You can replace Ubuntu(Unity) with Lubuntu(LXDE) or Xubuntu(XFCE).

Run this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Look also at this guide for more details [How to Install the Lightweight LXDE Desktop on Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/107368/how-to-install-the-lightweight-lxde-desktop-on-ubuntu/)

And if you want you can delete the unity desktop completly (**before you delete this you should make a backup**), run this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge unity unity-common unity-services unity-lens-\* unity-scope-\* unity-webapps-\* gnome-control-center-unity hud libunity-core-6\* libunity-misc4 libunity-webapps\* appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt\* overlay-scrollbar\* activity-log-manager-control-center firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu libufe-xidgetter0 xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-websites-integration gnome-control-center gnome-session
```

this will completly delete the unity desktop from Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, but I do not have an installation CD for XP, only a recovery DVD! I want to install Ubuntu alongside XP so that I can access the Internet via Ubuntu!

Comment: You can clone your whole disk with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable) (i486 should be the right iso for your hradware), [Video Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JsrlhBr0M8). So you do not need a XP CD for recover, but you need another HDD (or USB drive with enough space) for the Backup.

Comment: Before I received your answer, I already installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside XP. It's a pain. If i take your recommendation to install Xubuntu or Lubuntu, I need to remove the Ubuntu to set the space free on the HDD. So do I have problem or any help?

Comment: What did you mean with "it's a pain" it's to slow? There is no problem to replace the Ubuntu desktop with Lubuntu or Xubuntu. Look at my additions above in the answer.

Comment: There's no need to remove Ubuntu in order to install Xubuntu or Lubuntu. Either or both can be installed in Ubuntu and you choose which one you want when you boot into Ubuntu.

When you get to the login screen, there's a small symbol next to your password entry box. Click on it, and you can select which one you want. Ubuntu will remember this choice each time you login, or until you decide to change it.

Unlike Windows, the desktop environment is independent. You're free to choose which ones you want. Each has its strengths and weaknesses. XFCE (Xubuntu) is closer to Windows XP in features.

Comment: Installing Xubuntu or/and Lubuntu in instaled Ubuntu? Will this then require additional space in the Ubuntu-Partition? System performance would then be even slower?

Comment: Your system should be definitively faster with Lubuntu. It takes some space but not much i think max 300MB and if you want you can delete the old desktop as i described above that frees some space again.

Comment: OK, sounds good. But before proceeding, owing to concerns regarding limited resources (RAM 1 GB), Ubuntu-Partition on HDD 35GB, if I run into problems, can I uninstall Lubuntu in Ubuntu and how?            As I initially installed Ubuntu 14.4 LTS alongside XP, I forgot to create a swap partition. Is it possible to create such in retrospect on the existing Ubuntu-Partition? Would it have any effect?

Comment: @user277366 Swap should be created automatically if you use the option "Alongside Windows" (you can see your swap partitions with the command `cat /proc/swaps`). You do not need to uninstall Lubuntu, just don't erase Unity desktop so you can switch back if there are problems.

Comment: Hi Xubu-Tur,Have I understood this correctly, that the only difference in ubuntu and lubuntu lies in the different desktops i.e.the "look and feel" aspect???

Comment: Lubuntu desktop is a lightweight desktop and runs faster on older machines.

Comment: Is Lubuntu a stand-alone OS or is it part of Ubuntu??

Comment: Lubuntu is a [Flavor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) of Ubuntu. You can install it without Unity (the standard Ubuntu desktop) if you just download the Lubuntu CD http://releases.ubuntu.com/. But this requires a fresh install, the over way i described above.